# Why would an Injector and the Idle Control Solenoid be linked?

Tags: engine-theory, subaru, wiring, svx, eg33

I'm currently working on a 92 Subaru SVX wiring harness. I'm tearing it apart so I can use the engine side of the wiring harness to run the H6 EG33 engine I pulled out of the car. We are transplanting it into a 96 Subaru Impreza, which came with the H4 EJ22 engine. In tearing the wiring harness apart, I have depinned the ECU connectors (physically took the wires out of the connectors which go into the ECU). This is in an attempt to remove the parts of the wiring harness which I need without destroying the harness in the process. This is quite a chore, to say the least.

While tearing the wiring harness apart, I've run into something which seems quite odd to me. While pulling the wires apart, I've come across two wires which were numbered (I labeled *everything*) A2 & A13. They are aligned as such:

- A2 - Idle Control Solenoid - OPEN
- A13 - Injector #1

The strange thing is, these two wires are connected and are the same color pattern (white with red stripe).

Question: Does anyone know why Subaru did this or why they are connected together?

These two "things" seem completely separate to me. I don't know why they'd be connected together.

Bonus question: Is the EG33 from this year batch fired or sequential fired at the injectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wires you uncovered are powered by the main relay and are ignition voltage for the ECM, injectors and o2 sensors.

The idle air control solenoid is on a different branch and connector.

The two wires are labeled correctly. Maybe recheck that, that wire actually goes to the idle air solenoid.

From the wiring diagram it looks to be sequential firing.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If I'm reading this right, it provides power to both O2 sensors, as well as all six injectors ... is that what you are seeing as well? Then it must ground them through the ECU to provide the continuity and to fire each of the injectors. Unless something is done inside the ECU to fire each one, I'd suggest you are right on the sequential. TY

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes, looking at the pin out chart and the wiring diagram the idle air solenoid doesn't seem to be part of that circuit at all. And yes sequential.

Comment: I think the guy who originally diagramed this out miss labeled their diagram a little. All of *my labels* coming off of the connectors are correct.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 weird does it match the pinout chart? that should be from a subaru service manual.

Comment: The colors match what you've given me and I'm taking it as gospel. Your pinout chart is awesome. The ones I have are pared down versions done by someone other than Subaru ... believe me, these are awesome :o) I wish I could read them when I print them out, lol.

Comment: In the third chart, can you tell me how the connector number aligns with the socket letter? I guess I could figure it out ... just take some prodding around.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I added the connector and other page of the pin out. B59 is connector A.

Comment: Makes sense ... thank you for your time and efforts on this ... I'm sure I'll have more questions on this whole thing upcoming. Keep your SVX rolodex handy, lol.

Answer (score 2):

Paul...  here's what I have, one picture entitled "Control System Idle" and the other "Fuel Injectors".

Gosh dayum, the quality of '92 Subaru wiring diagrams leaves everything to be desired.  *Everything*.   Anyhow, I have "all" the diagrams, which unfortunately seem devoid of wire colors, but at least there's a few pin numbers.

Note this is for the '92 SVX H6.   I have *way* better stuff for the '96 Imprezzza if needed.  (My DD is a '97).

Hope it helps...

[image: Idle Control]

[image: Injection]

Comment: Unless something peaks it's head, I think I'm going to have to go with @Ben's answer on this one. I'm sure I'll be asking more questions, though.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 FINE!  All my stuff is poop, Ben's is golden.  [*But it's true; I totally want to know where Ben got those diags!*]